# Calculate the difference between number from user input

Tags: javascript, html

This should be a no brainer but i have no experience in Javascript and i can't see why this should not work.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Undantag</title>
  <p> STD: </p>
  <input type="number" name="STD">
  <p> STA: </p>
  <input type="number" name="STA">
  <p> ATD: </p>
  <input type="number" name="ATD">
  <p> ATA: </p>
  <input type="number" name="ATA">


<button onclick="useUndantag()">Click me</button>


</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function useUndantag()  {
        var a = document.getElementsByName("STD"); 
        var b = document.getElementsByName("ATD");
        var c = document.getElementsByName("STA");
        var d = document.getElementsByName("ATA");


        if (a-b >1) {
        alert("No undantag");
        }
            else if (d-c >2) {
                alert ("No undantag");

                else () {
                    alert ("NO EU FOR YOU!")

                }

            }
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that i get no alert at all and i can't seem to figure out why. If anyone has any tips if would be very glad for any help i can get.

Comment: I think you have a syntax error. It should be `else{...}` instead of `else (){....}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `getElementsByName` returns a collection of HTML elements. Use `[0]` to access the first element. Next, you must use `parseFloat` or `parseInt` to parse the inputs as integers/floats. Also, HTML code goes in the `body` tag *unless* you have scripts, links, meta, title, and other tags. Finally, you have an syntax error:

```
else () { }
```

Should not have parentheses. You're also missing a brace after the `else if`, remove a closing brace after the else. Here's a fixed snippet:

```js
    function useUndantag()  {
        var a = document.getElementsByName("STD")[0].value; 
        var b = document.getElementsByName("ATD")[0].value;
        var c = document.getElementsByName("STA")[0].value;
        var d = document.getElementsByName("ATA")[0].value;

        if (parseInt(a) - parseInt(b) > 1) { //notice the use of parseInt, you can use parseFloat to deal with decimals
            alert("No undantag");
        } else if(parseInt(d) - parseInt(c) > 2) {
            alert("No undantag");
        } else { //Notice no parentheses and some more braces
            alert("NO EU FOR YOU!")
        }
    }
```

```html
<p> STD: </p> <!-- HTML is in body tag !-->
<input type="number" name="STD">
<p> STA: </p>
<input type="number" name="STA">
<p> ATD: </p>
<input type="number" name="ATD">
<p> ATA: </p>
<input type="number" name="ATA">


<button onclick="useUndantag()">Click me</button>
```

Also, make sure you use `.value` to get the value.

Comment: You really helped me out, i have never used Javascript earlier, i will get his done then try to study up more. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @OscarAndersson If I did help, please consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect.

Also, if you are comparing the values of the inputs then you need to get the `value` attribute of the input.

Also, `document.getElementsByName` returns an array of elements so you need to select the first element.

Here is a working example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Undantag</title>
</head>

<body>
  
  <p> STD: </p>
  <input type="number" name="STD">
  <p> STA: </p>
  <input type="number" name="STA">
  <p> ATD: </p>
  <input type="number" name="ATD">
  <p> ATA: </p>
  <input type="number" name="ATA">

  <button onclick="useUndantag()">Click me</button>

  <script>
  
    function useUndantag() {
      var a = document.getElementsByName("STD")[0].value;
      var b = document.getElementsByName("ATD")[0].value;
      var c = document.getElementsByName("STA")[0].value;
      var d = document.getElementsByName("ATA")[0].value;

      if (a - b > 1) {
        alert("No undantag");
      } else if (d - c > 2) {
        alert("No undantag");
      } else {
        alert("NO EU FOR YOU!")
      }
    }
    
  </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have enough errors

the function

```
document.getElemenstByName
```

return an array!

```
    var a = document.getElementsByName("STD")[0].value; 
    var b = document.getElementsByName("ATD")[0].value;
    var c = document.getElementsByName("STA")[0].value;
    var d = document.getElementsByName("ATA")[0].value;
```

and you have sentences misdeclared

here code:
https://jsfiddle.net/evpog628/1/

Answer (score 0):

1) It's better to use `getElementById()`, it's faster and you select only one element ("id" must be unique in HTML document).

2) Be sure to use correct HTML structure

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input>
        <script>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

3) You need to be sure you get integer or float values from HTML fields to make your code work correctly. `parseInt()` or `pareseFloat()`.

```
<!doctype html>    
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">    
  <title>Undantag</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p> STD: </p><input type="number" id="STD">
  <p> STA: </p><input type="number" id="STA">
  <p> ATD: </p><input type="number" id="ATD">
  <p> ATA: </p><input type="number" id="ATA">

<button onclick="useUndantag();">Click me</button>
  <script>
    function useUndantag()  {
        var a = document.getElementById("STD"); 
        var b = document.getElementById("ATD");
        var c = document.getElementById("STA");
        var d = document.getElementById("ATA");

        if (parseInt(a.value)-parseInt(b.value)>1) {
            alert("No undantag");
        }
        else if (parseInt(d.value)-parseInt(c.value) >2) 
        {
            alert ("No undantag");
        }
        else 
        {
            alert ("NO EU FOR YOU!");
        }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code without explanation helps no one! Please add an explanation to better the answer!

Comment: @Adnrew L. you are right, i'll do better next time. I just wanted to post a working solution. I hope he will study the code on all working examples and learn from it.

Comment: You're code doesn't work. The HTML is incorrect because those tags shouldn't go in the head and the JS is not right, just some critiques.